# Understanding Multivariate Logistic Normal pdf

Tags: logistic, normal-distribution, logit, dirichlet-distribution

I'm trying to understand the Multivariate Logistic Normal distribution, in order to plot its pdf and compare it with a Dirichlet distribution.

I believe I can follow the pdf derivation for the univariate case, where *x* and *1-x* could be seen as probabilities in a binary event.

However, when I try to visualize this for three probabilities *( x, y, z=1-(x+y) )*, I can't understand why, in some sources, the multivariate pdf is expressed as:

[image: Multivariate Logistic Normal distribution]

where *x_D* refers to D-1 components of x.

Concretely, in my case (x is 3-D), I can't see why the log is taken on a 2-D vector. Assuming that the mean should be 3-D, this subtraction should fail, isn't it?

I'd assume I missed something here due to my lack of background. I'll be very grateful if you could tell me how to obtain that logit.